# How can I change the format to a popup calendar in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

I set the format in the cell to DD/MM/YY but when I click on that cell, I get a popup calendar with the week starting with Monday. But I want the calendar to start on Sunday. My Google Calendar is set to start on Sunday so I'm not sure why this is happening. See image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The pop-up calendar marks the first day of the week according to the locale set in your account (not just in an individual spreadsheet).

Try choosing a different account locale at https://myaccount.google.com/language. You will first need to choose a language and then a country/locale.

For instance, the United States has a default calendar that starts on Sunday.

This is not ideal for some. But to my knowledge, it is the only way to set the calendar start day differently.

Answer (score -1):

I've got the opposite problem: In Google calendar I can set the week to start on Monday as I would like.
But in the popup calendar in google sheets the week always starts on Sunday.  I've tried changing language between and locale but no matter what I do I can't get the popup week to start on Monday.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/155000)